# How increase Apache httpd max open files

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd

I have tried increasing apache httpd max open files in various files that were given as a solution in my Google searches but for no avail: cat /proc/x/limits keeps showing same value of 4k

Comment: Are you trying to change the  limits of a running Linux process? that value that you could get with ulimit -a    (open files) ??????

Comment: No, I have changed various files and made reboots or executed commands that were said to instantly change open files limit if I restart httpd